# Regular expressions: Matching last occurence of a repeating pattern

Tags: regex

Is there a way to write a regular expression that matches the last occurence of a repeating pattern. For example:

With this text:

> server_name{abc.com; random text;} server_name{xyz.com; more text;}

the match should be **server_name{xyz.com; more text;}**

And with the text:

> server_name{abc.com; random text;} server_name{cde.com more random
>   text;} server_name{xyz.com; more text;}

the match would still be **server_name{xyz.com; more text;}**

The stuff between {} can vary. And the regexp would match always only the last pattern with server_name{whatever text here;}

I have been testing with https://www.regexpal.com/
The following regex matches all the server_name{} -patterns, not just the last one. I've tried to use negative lookaheads with no luck.

```
server_name\{(.|\n)+?;\}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a negative [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!` that asserts that the pattern  `server_name{[^}]+})` is not occuring anymore.

[`server_name{[^}]+}(?!.*server_name{[^}]+})`](https://regex101.com/r/qpUitD/1)

**That would match**

- `server_name` Match literally
- `{[^}]+}` Match `{`, match not `}` one or more times and match `}`. That would for example match `{abc.com; random text;}`
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that asserts what is on the right side

  - `.*server_name{[^}]+}` Match any character zero or more times and then match your pattern
- `)` Close lookahead

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** This answer relies on the `\K` token available in PCRE, Perl and others since OP did not specify the flavor of his regex.

Add `.*\K` to the beginning of your regex. It matches any number of any character, then resets the reported match.

As recommended by ctwheels, I have changed your `(.|\n)` to `[\s\S]` (match any whitespace or non-whitespace character).

Full regex:

```
.*\Kserver_name\{[\s\S]+?;\}
```

Try it online [here](https://regex101.com/r/nNDDwj/1).

Comment: The `\K` metacharacter is new to me, so [here's some more info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) on it if it's new to anyone else too.

Comment: Good to know btw. However, my concern about this answer is that `\K` is somewhat specific to a subset of regex flavours but the OP didn't specify what language/flavour he is using. It might be worth clarifying that.

Comment: Definitely should determine which language OP is using before introducing `\K` token. Also, using `[\s\S]` or `.` with `DOTALL` flag is much better than using `(.|\n)`. It performs **much** better and doesn't create a group for no reason.

Comment: @ctwheels agreed – I just copied the OP's regex.

Comment: @O.O.Balance you should make improvements on their original ideas to give them the best approach (or what you believe to be the best approach). You're entitled to change what the OP posts to get a better working set of code. This not only improves the OP's code, but it leads to a better overall SO community since other users may use your code (or a portion thereof). Don't hesitate to add additional changes you see beneficial and let the OP know why you're making those changes or explain them so that they understand why that approach is best.